# Docker container crashes only when binding volumes due to a missing node module

Tags: node.js, docker

I want to bind a volume from my host to a docker container so that changes made in the host are reflected in the container.

I have a Node.js app structured as:

```
...
publc/
  |_index.html
  |_ ...
src/
  |_app.js
  |_ ...
package.json
...
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14

# app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# bundle app source

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3016
CMD ["node", "src/app.js"]
```

Creating image (within project dir):

```
$ docker build . -t node-docker-img
```

Running Docker container (within project dir):

```
docker run -p 8160:3016 -d -v "$(pwd)":/app node-docker-img
```

The Docker container immediately exits.
When viewing Docker logs, I see:

```
nternal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
Require stack:
- /app/src/app.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/app.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/app/src/app.js' ]
}
```

If I instead run the docker container without binding a volume, the app works fine.

```
docker run -p 8160:3016 -d node-docker-img
```

How can I bind a volume from my host to the Docker container so that changes made in the host are propagated to the container while not having Docker crash from being able to find a module?

Comment: Docker volumes by default bind volumes in both directions ( container->machine, machine->container) . Verify that you're running the docker run command in the target directory while you are using  pwd , verify if the volume is created successfully when running the image ($ docker volumes ls )  if yes share the inspect desc ( $ docker volume inspect <target_volume>).

Comment: I ran `docker volume ls`, and see two columns: `DRIVER` and `VOLUME NAME`. The rows of `DRIVER` are all `local`. The rows of `VOLUME NAME` are long hex looking strings e.g. `1e884e8e4b4a99eb0f0b66b9319bb23a734c6f1be2589914a75b9be8c833745e`. When I inspect the latest volume, I get:
```
{...
"Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/1e884e8e4b4a99eb0f0b66b9319bb23a734c6f1be2589914a75b9be8c833745e/_data",
        "Name": "1e884e8e4b4a99eb0f0b66b9319bb23a734c6f1be2589914a75b9be8c833745ee",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
```

Comment: I think this is not a docker issue verify the node app modules configuration,
to guarantee that,  run your image in interactive mode and check the shared resources directories in the container, you'll find resources in place obviously  (volume working fine). retry the test and verify by running your app. 
To run an image  in interactive mode : ` $ docker run -p 8160:3016 -it -v "$(pwd)":/app node-docker-img /bin/sh `

Answer (score 0):

What is your operating system: windows (wsl)/linux/macOs?

try run this command: docker run -p 8160:3016 -d -v $(pwd):/app node-docker-img

I've changed "$(pwd)" to $(pwd).

Comment: If you are using windows(wsl), "$(pwd)" don't have the same result as $(pwd) that's why i've changed it.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, `echo $(pwd)` and `echo "$(pwd)"` return the same thing for me